# Remove One Month Data from a BigQuery Table via Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to Remove data from One month (July) but I can't manage to write properly the SQL query in the console.

I have tried the following code and worked fine. I just need to find to way to write the range of one complete month (July).

```
DELETE 
FROM Sandbox.SandboxTable
where Date = '2018-12-09T00:00:00'
```

I have tried different possibilities but had syntax errors. I will strongly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE

FROM Sandbox.SandboxTable

where

Date >= '2018-07-01T00:00:00' AND Date <= '2018-07-31T23:59:59'
```

Comment: It Worked! I strongly appreciate your help